# PLC Best Naming Conventions for RSLogix 5000

Tags: naming-conventions, plc

What good naming conventions do you use for PLC?

I've seen hundreds of projects from different programmers, dozens of companies standards, RA, Beckhoff posted in some documents their naming... dozens of different ideas.

For years, naming tags was one of the most difficult task for me. You can't imagine discussion when I ask a student to create a bit. It's like being the hardest thing on Earth :) (usually, after creating a_bit and another_bit, inspiration is gone).

I asked for RSLogix 5000 because I found it most flexible, having tags, alias, scope tags, descriptions(stored in CPU for latest versions).

Have some tips to share that you find suitable for your use?

Answer (score 1):

Naming tags should have a refrence to the real world. A recent example I did was this:

PTK3KOS1
Pressure Transmitter Kettle 3 Kettle Overhead Solvent #1
This is the tag used in the CMMS system (Maintenance system), and the P&ID

I use UDT's in RSL5K, so that becomes the following in RSLogix:
PTK3KOS1.VAL (Current value)
PTK3KOS1.MIN (I use this especially when I use flex I/O for scaling)
PTK3KOS1.MAX (And I also use it to pass min/max values to some HMI's like WW)
PTK3KOS1.LFF (Signal fault)
PTK3KOS1.LLA (Low alarm bit)
PTK3KOS1.LLL (Low Low bit)
PTK3KOS1.LHA (Hi Alarm bit)
PTK3KOS1.LHH (Hi Hi Bit)
PTK3KOS1.SLA (Setpoint low alarm)
PTK3KOS1.SLL
PTK3KOS1.SHA
PTK3KOS1.SHH

The most common system is the ISA system, see
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/isa-intrumentation-codes-d_415.html for an example.

There is also the KKS system, which I personally believe was designed by masochists, and will only use it when forced to do so.
http://www.vgb.org/en/db_kks_eng.html

Answer (score 0):

I like to use some thing like this:

aabccdd_eeee_human-readable-name_wirenumber

**aa**

```
DO=Digital Output 
DI=Digital Input 
AO=Analog Output 
AI=Analog Input 
gl=Global variable 
co=constant 
pt=produced Tag 
ct=consumed Tag
```

**b**

```
Rack Number
```

**cc**

```
Slot
```

**dd**

```
address 0-64
```

**eeeee**

```
panel/drawing tag
```

DO10606_MA949_WshLoaderAdvance_9491